# Flutter Cannot load settings from file iml does not exist

Tags: flutter

I am seeing such errors when starting up Android Studio and Gradle is launching. I tried flutter repair cache etc. Any tips?

```
6:48    Load Settings
        Cannot load settings from file '\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.5\android\cloud_firestore.iml': File \flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.5\android\cloud_firestore.iml does not exist
        Please correct the file content

6:48    Load Settings
        Cannot load settings from file '\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore_web-0.1.1+2\android\cloud_firestore_web.iml': File \flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore_web-0.1.1+2\android\cloud_firestore_web.iml does not exist
        Please correct the file content
```

Comment: Android studio **File menu**  -> **invalidate caches and restart**

Comment: Yes, tried that but no luck

Comment: oh ok. Tried `flutter clean` ?

Comment: Yep, even deleting the pub cache folder and redownloading it. Seems like sg is wrong with the pub package itself.

Comment: Any updates on that? I'm also facing this issue